# How to use f:validateRegex on a numeric value

Tags: jsf

I used this regex `^(\+968|968|00968)?\d{8}$` for a phone number. It must be 8 digits and start with 9 or 7.

```html
<p:inputText value="#{customer.phoneNo}" maxlength="8" required="true" 
             validatorMessage="Phone Number Should be 8 digits and start with 9,7">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^(\+968|968|00968)?\d{8}$"/>
    <f:validateLength minimum="8" maximum="8"/>
    <p:keyFilter mask="num"/>
</p:inputText>
```

but I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

In the bean phone number is an `Integer`.

Comment: Off topic: try https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/inputphone.jsf

Comment: Phone numbers are not integers in first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f:validateRegex` expects a `String` value (or `CharSequence` depending on the JSF implementation), so it cannot be used on an `Integer`. So you need to use a `String` value in your UI and convert that to numeric before saving it to the database. You could use an `AttributeConverter` for that if you are using JPA. But I must say that storing a phone number as a numeric database field is a strange choice in my opinion.

See also:

- https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/jakarta/faces/validator/RegexValidator.java
- https://github.com/apache/myfaces/blob/master/api/src/main/java/jakarta/faces/validator/RegexValidator.java

Answer (score -1):

It means java.lang.Integer cannot be java.lang.String you need to convert it.

Comment: how ? im saving  the phone number to the database , this is for registration of a customer and the phone number is integer in my database